# TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined,;

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have a problem with the main.js file for the play.js command.

When I check console it's saying that problem is right here:

```js
client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args);
                                   ^
```

Here is the play.js command:

```js
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const ytSearch = require("yt-search");

module.exports = {
    name: "play",
    description: "Play Komanda",
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("Moraš biti u nekom kanalu kako bi koristio ovu komandu!");
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has("CONNECT")) return message.channel.send("Nemaš permisije!");
        if (!permissions.has("SPEAK")) return message.channel.send("Nemaš permisiju!");
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send("Moraš poslati drugi argumenat.");

        const validURL = (str) => {
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if (!regex.test(str)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        };

        if (validURL(args[0])) {
            const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream = ytdl(args[0], { filter: "audioonly" });

            connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 }).on("finish", () => {
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send("leaving channel");
            });

            await message.reply(`:musical_note: Trenutno slušaš ***Your Link!***`);

            return;
        }

        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

            return videoResult.videos.length > 1 ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
        };

        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(" "));

        if (video) {
            const stream = ytdl(video.url, { filter: "audioonly" });
            connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 1 }).on("finish", () => {
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });

            await message.reply(`:musical_note: Trenutno slušaš ***${video.title}***`);
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Nijedan video nije pronadjen");
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Can you log this: `console.log(client.commands.get('play'))` and check if it's empty / undefined or not

Comment: Also, can you show us the code where you **set** all your commands?

Comment: @Toasty It says it's undefined

Comment: Are you even **setting** your commands? Like in your `index.js` or command handler?

Comment: @Toasty if u mean like this ( https://prnt.sc/1g66ofj ) ye.

Comment: No, in this pic you're **getting** commands

Comment: @Toasty Can u give me your discord, 
if you would like to explain to me in chat?

Comment: Try my suggested answer first and if that don't work, you can go to my profile, I linked my Discord server there

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting this **error** because you're never **setting** the commands.  is just a **collection** you have to fill by yourself in order to use `.get()`.

To fix this, you may try something like that (for example in your `index.js`):

```js
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    // Set the command equal to the file
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    // Add the command to the collection
    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

##### But...

...this requires all of your commands to be in seperate files in a folder called `commands` (if your bot isn't already structured like this)

Comment: Does this fix your problem?